# Gitignore doesnot ignore files

Tags: git

my git is not ignoring some files and folder.

this is my git status

```
deleted:    storage/app/some_folder/700
```

> 700 is a file, without extension

my .gitignore

```
/storage/*.key
/storage/app/
```

Comment: `.gitignore` does not mean *ignore* a file, it means *don't complain about the file being untracked* and *don't automatically add the file when using an en-masse "add many" operation*. A *tracked* file (which is now in the index/staging-area) cannot be ignored, it has to be explicitly removed (using `git rm`) from the index/staging-area.

Answer (score 4):

When you have added your files first it's insight the git repo and tracked until you remove the files. So remove the files first and then your files are ignored.

```
git rm --cached yourfiles
```

Then your files are removed for the next commit but still present in your folder. Then you can add the deleted files and they are removed.

Comment: deleted:    storage/app/my_folder/150
        git rm --cached 150
it is still tracking this.. can you explain me, what's going here

Comment: First reset your delete. `git checkout .` then delete the file `git rm --cached storage/app/my_folder/` something like this. You have to define the whole path.

Comment: its not allowing me to delete, until it is not a recursive delete..

Comment: Then add the parameter `-r` for recursive delete ;)

Comment: Note: the files are *not* "removed from the repo". They are removed from new commits, but existing commits that already have those files continue to have those files.

Comment: @torek you're right. They are removed with the next commit. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.gitignore` is ignoring the folder, but not the files within it. As far as git is concerned, folders aren't even real! Add a wildcard to get it to ignore the contents of the folder:

```
/storage/*.key
/storage/app/*
```

Comment: Somebody keeps downvoting all the answers I post within 30 seconds of posting them. Cut it out please. I appreciate that this one might be wrong, since ot's based on a vague recollection, but it would be nice if you'd told me that.